# Need help correcting an XSS vulnerability in my code

Tags: javascript, security, xss

It was brought to my attention that my image popup code is subject to an XSS attack.. I understand the issue, but as PHP is not my area of expertise, I am not sure how to correct it.. I've done a fair bit of searching here, but still am not fully clear on HOW to fix my code.

Here's the code that is problematic:

```
<?php
  echo '<a href="javascript:window.close()">' . zen_image($_GET['products_image_large_additional'], $products_values->fields['products_name'] . ' ' . TEXT_CLOSE_WINDOW) . '</a>';
?>
```

How do I correct this code to correct the XSS vulnerability in it??

Comment: What does `zen_image` do?

Comment: It's a function which returns the image data (image source, alt tag, width, height, etc)

Comment: How exactly does it do that? Could you show some code, especially how the first parameter is processed?

Comment: Let me try this again.. 

zen_image is "The HTML image wrapper function". (image source, alt tag, width, height, etc)

Comment: Ok, so [`zen_image` is from Zen Cart](http://sourceforge.net/p/zencart/code/39/tree/branches/v1-5-0/trunk/includes/functions/html_output.php#l160), right?

Comment: Yes.. trying to resolve an issue I discovered working on a client site.. and YES I already tried asking in the support forum, but have been striking out..

Answer (score 0):

You're obviously getting the product's data on the server-side
(`$products_values->fields['products_name']`), so why not get the image in the same way instead of passing it through `$_GET`? That should fix your problem.

Comment: Even if I knew how to do what you are suggesting (I don't since PHP programming is not a skillset I possess :) ) I do know that the code I posted is for the ADDITIONAL product images and since the product data only stores the main product image, I do not believe I can get the additional images in this manner..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `zen_image` expects/does, but you could escape the GET variables before passing them to the function.

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="javascript:window.close()">' . zen_image(strip_tags($_GET['products_image_large_additional']), $products_values->fields['products_name'] . ' ' . TEXT_CLOSE_WINDOW) . '</a>';
?>
```

I used the function [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove any HTML tags.

Comment: zen_image is "The HTML image wrapper function". (image source, alt tag, width, height, etc)

Comment: So one followup question -- because I want to walk away from this understanding the fix you suggest :).. Why strip_tags versus htmlspecialchars?? Just want to understand for a go forward basis.. You code seems to work just fine..

Comment: @CrystalJones It depends on how the HTML is broken. htmlspecialchars would work as well. strip_tags removes tags, htmlspecialchars encode them so the browser don't render them as tags. Make sure you add ** ENT_QUOTES** as the second parameter if you use htmlspecialchars.